# Evaluate $ \int\left(x^{3} + x^{6}\right)\left(x^{3} + 2\right)^{1/3} \,\mathrm{d} x $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate :
$$
\int\left(x^{3} + x^{6}\right)\left(x^{3} + 2\right)^{1/3}
\,\mathrm{d} x
$$
I have tried assuming that ${{x}^{3}}+2$ term as ${u}^{3}$, $dx=u^2du/(u^3-2)^{2/3}$
$$
\int\left(x^{3} + x^{6}\right)u
\,\mathrm{d} x=\int (u^3-2)(u^3-1)u
\,\frac{u^2du}{(u^3-2)^{2/3}}
$$  $$
=\int 
\,\frac{u^3(u^6-3u^3+2) du}{(u^3-2)^{2/3}}
$$

but that does not take me anywhere. Please provide an alternate approach or help me how to proceed after this step.

Comment: Did you mean to type $x^6+x^6$?

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=1+x^3$:
$$I=\frac{1}{3} \int  t {\left(t-1\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}   {\left(t+1\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} \; dt$$
$$I=\frac{1}{3} \int  t   {\left(t^2-1\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} \; dt$$
Finally, let $\xi=t^2-1$:
$$I=\frac{1}{6} \int {\xi}^{\frac{1}{3}} \; d\xi$$
$$I=\frac{{\xi}^{\frac{4}{3}}}{8}+C$$
Substitute back to $t$:
$$I=\frac{{\left(t^2-1\right)}^{\frac{4}{3}}}{8}+C$$
Substitute back to $x$:
$$I=\frac{{\left(x^6+2x^3\right)}^{\frac{4}{3}}}{8}+C$$
$$\boxed{I=\frac{x^4 {\left(x^3+2\right)}^{\frac{4}{3}}}{8}+C}$$

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right, I edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ty., How did you think about the 1+x^3 substitution

Comment: @ShriomKumarSingh Well, I rewrote the integrand as $x^3\left(x^3+1\right){\left((x^3+1)+1\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and tried $t=x^3+1$ because I thought it might work nicely.  For some reason the first time I tried that I messed up, so then I tried $t=\frac{1}{x}$ then $u=1+\frac{1}{t^3}$ worked (which is the same thing as $t=1+x^3$) and proceeded as shown in the answer.  Oddly enough, substituting $u=\frac{1}{x}$ as a last ditch effort with algebraic integrals like this works out more often than not from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid substitution as follows
$$\int (x^3+x^6)(x^3+2)^{1/3}\ dx=\int x(x^2+x^5)(x^3+2)^{1/3}\ dx$$
$$=\int (x^5+x^2)(x^6+2x^3)^{1/3}\ dx$$
$$=\frac16\int 6(x^5+x^2)(x^6+2x^3)^{1/3}\ dx$$
$$=\frac16\int (x^6+2x^3)^{1/3}\ d(x^6+2x^3)$$
$$=\frac16 \frac{(x^6+2x^3)^{4/3}}{4/3}+C$$
$$=\frac{(x^6+2x^3)^{4/3}}{8}+C$$